# Magento 2 - Redirect user to specific page after register

Tags: magento2, redirect, register

I write an observer to observe the `customer_register_success` event and run the following codes to do the redirect but failed. Can anyone help?

```
$url = $this->url->getUrl('/');
$observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
$this->logger->debug("Redirect to: {$url}");
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors? Is your debug message getting triggered?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think the problem is that your redirect is occuring *before* the default redirect and hence has no effect.
Here's a module that does the job:

Module directory structure:

```
|   registration.php
|   
+---etc
|   |   di.xml
|   |   module.xml
|   |   
|   \---frontend
|           events.xml
|           
+---Observer
|       Register.php
|       
\---Plugin
        Redirect.php
```

**di.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect">
        <plugin name="NewAcctRedirectPlug" type="Your\Module\Plugin\Redirect" disabled="false" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

**events.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="custom_redirect_register_success" instance="Your\Module\Observer\Register" disabled="false"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**Register.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Your\Module\Observer;


use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Register implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $coreRegistry;

    public function __construct(Registry $registry)
    {
        $this->coreRegistry = $registry;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $this->coreRegistry->register('is_new_account', true);
    }
}
```

**Redirect.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Your\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class Redirect
{
    protected $coreRegistry;

    protected $url;

    protected $resultFactory;

    public function __construct(Registry $registry, UrlInterface $url, ResultFactory $resultFactory)
    {
        $this->coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
    }

    public function aroundGetRedirect ($subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {
        if ($this->coreRegistry->registry('is_new_account')) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $result */
            $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $result->setUrl($this->url->getUrl('custom/path'));
            return $result;
        }

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

It works by setting a flag in the core registry when the `customer_register_success` event occurs and then checks for that flag and returns an alternate redirect path when the redirect for a successful customer authentication is requested instead of the default 'My Account' page. Hope this helps.

Comment: It does not work and it display an error in the create account page: `We can't save the customer.`. But the account is actually created successfully and the welcome email is sent out successfully too.

Comment: You should check the var/log/system.log file to see what the error is. I tested the module and it works in 2.1, can't vouch for other versions.

Comment: I removed all files under var/* and tried again. It works now. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks it worked like charm in my end! been looking for this one. Keep sharing :)

Comment: I have a question about this one. I'm having a problem with the website. If I log out the user it will give me an error. and if I go to the homepage it is not logged in, but if I visit on other pages of the site it is working fine. Thanks

Comment: How to get customer details in aroundGetRedirect?

Comment: Facing the same problem, Its not working in home page. The action does not goes to the Redirect.php it goes till Register.php:

Comment: @AaronAllen observer is working fine but plugin is not working it is redirecting to my account page instead of custom page.

Comment: @AaronAllen,Why we need  observer as we are already plugin to override the core file?Please clarify it more.

Comment: Thanks, it works on Magento 2.3.5p1 ! I replaced 'custom/path' with 'checkout'

Comment: It does not work and it display an error in the create account page: We can't save the customer.. in M 2.4.2 version. Any help for this version?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be using the after plugin.

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost">
        <plugin name="VendorCustomerCreatePost"
                type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CustomerCreatePost"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/CustomerCreatePost.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class CustomerCreatePost
{
    private RedirectFactory $redirectFactory;
    private CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface;

    public function __construct(
        RedirectFactory $redirectFactory,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
    )
    {
        $this->redirectFactory = $redirectFactory;
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    }

    /**
     * @param CreatePost $subject
     * @param Redirect $result
     * @return Redirect
     */
    public function afterExecute(CreatePost $subject, Redirect $result): Redirect
    {
        $request    = $subject->getRequest();
        $emailPost  = $request->getParam('email');
        try {
            $customer = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->get($emailPost);
            $customerId = $customer->getId();

            if($customerId){
                $url = 'https://example.com/custom-page-uri';
                return $this->redirectFactory->create()
                    ->setUrl($url);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```