# Two functions on submit button Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, popup, registration, submission

i want my vendor registration form to show a video popup when click on submit button. 
`<button type="submit" id="save" class="action submit primary" onclick="submit"title="Save"><span><?php echo __('Save'); ?></span></button>`
can anyone kindly and please help me fast on this?

Comment: could you explain the scenario, When form will be submitted ? when registration data will be submitted ?

Comment: WHEN DATA OF REGISTRATION FORM IS SUBBMITED.

Comment: AFTER FILLING THE FORM WHEN USER CLICKS "SAVE" IE. SUBMIT BUTTON. I WANT TO POPUP A VIDEO ON THIS ACTION

Comment: if video will popup then when registration data will be submitted ? so there will be another page when registration is completed and video will show up ?

Comment: YES THATS WHAT I WANT TO DO

Comment: CAN UH GUIDE ME THE CODE PLZ

Comment: are you using some extension for vendor registration ?

Comment: WELL YES ITS VENDOR REGISTRATION FORM I'VE GOT ITS FILE reister.phtml

Comment: @Naveed arent uh gonna help me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75061/discussion-between-naveed-and-laiba).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - create a cms page and have your video added on that page.

Step 2 - you have to override the CreatePost controller of magento-customer module and redirect customer to that cms page.

You have to write a simple module to override that functionality , you can check this link for detailed step how to implement that functionality.

[Magento 2 - Redirect user to specific page after register](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131850/magento-2-redirect-user-to-specific-page-after-register/131867)