# How to redirect customer on custom page after registration in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, event-observer, redirect

Here is my code

> customerregistersuceessobserver.php

```
    <?php


namespace Webkul\Marketplace\Observer\Rewrite;
use Webkul\Marketplace\Observer\CustomerRegisterSuccessObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Webkul\Marketplace\Model\ResourceModel\Seller\CollectionFactory;


class CustomerRewriteRegisterSuccessObserver extends CustomerRegisterSuccessObserver
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime
     */
    protected $_date;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    private $_messageManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface   $objectManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface  $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
     * @param CollectionFactory                           $collectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_date = $date;
    }

    /**
     * customer register event handler.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $data = $observer['account_controller'];
        try {
            $paramData = $data->getRequest()->getParams();
            if (!empty($paramData['is_seller']) && !empty($paramData['selling_categories']) && $paramData['is_seller'] == 1) {
                $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

                //~ $profileurlcount = $this->_objectManager->create(
                    //~ 'Webkul\Marketplace\Model\Seller'
                //~ )->getCollection();
                //~ $profileurlcount->addFieldToFilter(
                    //~ 'selling_categories',
                    //~ $paramData['selling_categories']
                //~ );
                //~ if (!$profileurlcount->getSize()) {
                    $status = $this->_objectManager->get(
                        'Webkul\Marketplace\Helper\Data'
                    )->getIsPartnerApproval() ? 0 : 1;
                    $customerid = $customer->getId();
                    $model = $this->_objectManager->create(
                        'Webkul\Marketplace\Model\Seller'
                    );
                    $categories=implode(',',$paramData['selling_categories']);
                    $model->setData('is_seller', $status);
                    $model->setData('selling_categories',$categories);
                    $model->setData('seller_id', $customerid);
                    $model->setData('store_id', 0);
                    $model->setCreatedAt($this->_date->gmtDate());
                    $model->setUpdatedAt($this->_date->gmtDate());
                    if ($status == 0) {
                        $model->setAdminNotification(1);
                    }
                    $model->save();
                    $loginUrl = $this->_objectManager->create(
                        'Magento\Framework\UrlInterface'
                    )->getUrl("marketplace/account/dashboard");
                    $this->_objectManager->create(
                        'Magento\Customer\Model\Session'
                    )->setBeforeAuthUrl($loginUrl);
                    $this->_objectManager->create(
                        'Magento\Customer\Model\Session'
                    )->setAfterAuthUrl($loginUrl);

                    $helper = $this->_objectManager->get(
                        'Webkul\Marketplace\Helper\Data'
                    );
                    //~ if ($helper->getAutomaticUrlRewrite()) {
                        //~ $this->createSellerPublicUrls($paramData['profileurl']);
                    //~ }
                    $adminStoremail = $helper->getAdminEmailId();
                    $adminEmail = $adminStoremail ? $adminStoremail : $helper->getDefaultTransEmailId();
                    $adminUsername = 'Admin';
                    $senderInfo = [
                        'name' => $customer->getFirstName().' '.$customer->getLastName(),
                        'email' => $customer->getEmail(),
                    ];
                    $receiverInfo = [
                        'name' => $adminUsername,
                        'email' => $adminEmail,
                    ];
                    $emailTemplateVariables['myvar1'] = $customer->getFirstName().' '.
                    $customer->getLastName();
                    $emailTemplateVariables['myvar2'] = $this->_objectManager->get(
                        'Magento\Backend\Model\Url'
                    )->getUrl(
                        'customer/index/edit',
                        ['id' => $customer->getId()]
                    );
                    $emailTemplateVariables['myvar3'] = 'Admin';

                    $this->_objectManager->create(
                        'Webkul\Marketplace\Helper\Email'
                    )->sendNewSellerRequest(
                        $emailTemplateVariables,
                        $senderInfo,
                        $receiverInfo
                    );







                //~ } else {
                    //~ $this->_messageManager->addError(
                        //~ __('This Shop URL already Exists.')
                    //~ );
                //~ }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

> here I need to redirect the customer after register in magento 2
>   how i can set redirect (note: email  verfication enabled)

how i can do this

> now it  redirects to the customer login page

Comment: If below answer not helpful then refer this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131850/magento-2-redirect-user-to-specific-page-after-register

Comment: no    here had some data process there .....
how i can add

Answer (score 0):

> Using Plugin :-

**di.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect">
        <plugin name="NewAcctRedirectPlug" type="Your\Module\Plugin\Redirect" disabled="false" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

**events.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="custom_redirect_register_success" instance="Your\Module\Observer\Register" disabled="false"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**Register.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Your\Module\Observer;


use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Register implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $coreRegistry;

    public function __construct(Registry $registry)
    {
        $this->coreRegistry = $registry;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $this->coreRegistry->register('is_new_account', true);
    }
}
```

**Redirect.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Your\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class Redirect
{
    protected $coreRegistry;

    protected $url;

    protected $resultFactory;

    public function __construct(Registry $registry, UrlInterface $url, ResultFactory $resultFactory)
    {
        $this->coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
    }

    public function aroundGetRedirect ($subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {
        if ($this->coreRegistry->registry('is_new_account')) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $result */
            $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $result->setUrl($this->url->getUrl('custom/path'));
            return $result;
        }

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is return $proceed(); for some reason after register i am getting return back to login page