# Magento 2 How to redirect customer to custom page after registration

Tags: customer-account, register, magento2.3.1

Actually i am going to "Send email to admin" after customer registration using events observer AND Redirect to customer to "custom page with customer logout".

Send email to admin is working fine but redirecting to my account page instead of custom page with logout.

I am following that answer - [Magento 2 - Redirect user to specific page after register](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131850/magento-2-redirect-user-to-specific-page-after-register)

Comment: Add log to your observer and plugin to check those are working fine or not? and you gotta logout when customer register success

Comment: ok i will add log in observer and how to check plugin working fine or not ?
yes i want logout when customer register success and redirect to custom page

Comment: that's fine then add the log in plugin too