# How to disable redirect dashboard after creating an account using the shopping cart?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

How to not be redirected to the dashbord after creating an account when validating the basket? Here is my configuration and the screenshots of the process:

## ***When Allow Guest Checkout is disable :***

[image: magento]

***And***

## ***Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging is disable :***

[image]

---

---

**> website/checkout/cart/**

[image]

**> website/checkout/cart/**

[image]

**> website/customer/account/create/**

[image]

**> website/customer/account/**

[image]

Comment: Your issue will be resolve by this [link](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Redirect-to-Account-Dashboard-During-Checkout-Funnel-Login/td-p/74271). Happy coding.

Comment: I just found, you have to make a module using this answer: [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131850/magento-2-redirect-user-to-specific-page-after-register](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131850/magento-2-redirect-user-to-specific-page-after-register)