# Magento 2.3 customer register after redirect to previous page

Tags: magento2.3, customer-account, register

In default magento functionality : 
`customer` register after redirect to
my account page but **I want to redirect previous page** 
My code :

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Registerredirect\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;
class Redirect
{
    protected $coreRegistry;

    protected $url;

    protected $resultFactory;

    public function __construct(Registry $registry, UrlInterface $url, ResultFactory $resultFactory, RedirectInterface $redirect)
    {
        $this->coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
    }

    public function aroundGetRedirect ($subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {
        if ($this->coreRegistry->registry('is_new_account')) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $result */
            $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $result->setUrl($this->redirect->getRefererUrl());
            return $result;
        }

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

any one know how to solve above code or other code if it is working ..  
Any idea how can achieve that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See this thread, it might help [enter link description here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134808/magento-2-redirect-customer-to-custom-page-after-login)

Comment: Check this link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131850/magento-2-redirect-user-to-specific-page-after-register

Comment: @SukumarGorai thanks and i have checked link and its going custom link is this possible to redirect previous page or code ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it does what you want but there is a setting under customers->customer configuration->login options that is called "Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in". Maybe disabeling this will do the job?

Comment: yes i have tried but it is only working for login form not register form

Answer (score 0):

Define path of file you want to redirect to like below, in getUrl

> $result->setUrl($this->url->getUrl('namespace/module/actionfile'));
> //('[Namespace]/[ModuleName]/[[Action]');

```
if ($this->coreRegistry->registry('is_new_account')) {
                /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $result */
                $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
                $result->setUrl($this->url->getUrl('namespace/module/actionfile')); //('[Namespace]/[ModuleName]/[[Action]');

                return $result;
            }
```